# declaring two object literals in (one?) data-ng-init and binding them to different views

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to create two different object literals and bind them to different views (`<table>`s). However, I'm not sure how to go about doing this. I've tried the below method where I declare both object literals in one `data-ng-init` of a parent container (the `div`). I've also tried having two different `data-ng-init` directives for that div and having one object literal in each of the directives. However both methods did not work and I get errors (will post if anyone would like to see them).

Example of what I've tried:

```
<div id="recipes" data-ng-init=" 
  dessertsdrinks = [
  {name: 'Apple Pie Popcorn',  url: 'pdfs/recipes/desserts_and_drinks/Apple Pie Popcorn.pdf'},  
  {name: 'Zucchini Muffins',  url: 'pdfs/recipes/Zucchini Muffins.pdf'} 
  ];

  maineats = [ 
  {name: 'Autumn Enchilada Casserole',  url: 'pdfs/recipes/Autumn Enchilada    Casserole.pdf'},
  {name: 'Build your own Taco',  url: 'pdfs/recipes/Build your own Taco.pdf'},]
  ">

  <table id="dessertsdrinks">
    <th>Desserts and Drinks</th>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="recipe in dessertsdrinks | filter:recipesearch | orderBy:'name'">
        <td><a href="{{ recipe.url }}"> {{ recipe.name }} </a></td>
        </tr>
   </table>

<table id="maineats">
        <th>Main Eats</th>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="recipe in maineats | filter:recipesearch | orderBy:'name'">
            <td><a href="{{ recipe.url }}"> {{ recipe.name }} </a></td>
            </tr>
       </table>
 </div>
```

When I only have one object literal and one `data-ng-init` it works perfectly. 
But how could I do this with two different lists? Is there a better way?

For example, could I have a controller which binds object literals to `$scope` based on the view's (table's) `id` tag or something? Like so :

**psuedocode**

```
function recipeController(){
     if $scope id == "desertsdrinks" {
          $scope.recipes = [{.. dessert and drink recipe obj literal ..}];
     } else if $scope id == "maineats" {
          $scope.recipes =[{.. main eats recipe obj literal..}];
     }
 }
```

Comment: Yup your intuition in the pseudo-code seems like a better idea, write the data for the lists into the scope in the controller.  You can still call ng-init="myInitFunction()" if you need to run something on init so long as $scope.myInitFunction = function(){};

Comment: Ah, okay. Do you know how to determine properties of the $scope's parent element? For example detect that the parent `<table>` of the scope has an `id` of `dessertsdrinks`?

Comment: Well I think you should just keep two arrays in your scope rather than try to figure out which element this controller is being applied to (if you're in fact creating a separate controller for each list/table)

Comment: Ah, I see. Similar to the suggestion as the answer below I think. Thanks for the advice~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply moving the objects inside the controller should work:

```
$scope.dessertsdrinks = [
  {name: 'Apple Pie Popcorn',  url: 'pdfs/recipes/desserts_and_drinks/Apple Pie Popcorn.pdf'},  
  {name: 'Zucchini Muffins',  url: 'pdfs/recipes/Zucchini Muffins.pdf'} 
];

$scope.maineats = [ 
  {name: 'Autumn Enchilada Casserole',  url: 'pdfs/recipes/Autumn Enchilada    Casserole.pdf'},
  {name: 'Build your own Taco',  url: 'pdfs/recipes/Build your own Taco.pdf'}
]
```

No need to change the way you access them inside the html.

Comment: It is much more common having generated html and fixed (minified, cached and browser-cached) javascript, so this is seldom a good way to feed data to the controller.

Answer (score -1):

You can also pass an object literal directly into the ng-init directive.  Each property (name is up to you) value will be evaluated and main avaialble on the scope.

`ng-init="{a: dessertDrinks = [...], b: maineats = [...]}"`

Comment: Did not work for me. But `"ng-init"="count=3; type='mini'"` worked!